# Problem involving 1st law of thermo and ideal gas law

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, differential-equations

Problem:

> $1.0 \text{ kg}$ of air at pressure $10^6 \text{ Pa}$ and temperature $398 \text{ K}$ expands to a five times greater volume. The expansion occurs such that in every instance the added heat is a quarter of the work done by the gas. Calculate the final pressure. $1 \text{ kmol}$ has a mass of $29 \text{ kg}$ and $C_V = \frac 52 R$.

I solved the problem but I have some questions regarding the approaches I made. I interpreted heat being a quarter of the work done every instance as $\text{d}Q = \frac 14 \text{d}W$. By the 1st law of thermodynamics ($Q = W + \Delta U$), this yields $-\frac 34 \text{d}W = \text{d}U$.

But for molar heat capacity we know that $\text{d}U = nC_V\text{d}T$, hence $-\frac 34 \text{d}W = nC_V\text{d}T$. By definition, $\text{d}W = p\text{d}V$ and therefore $-\frac 34 p\text{d}W = nC_V\text{d}T$. We treat the gas as ideal and thus we can substitute $\frac {nRT}V$ for $p$, arriving at $-\frac 34 \frac{nRT}V \text{d}V = nC_V\text{d}T$.

Separation of variables yield $-\frac 34 \frac{nR}V \text{d}V = \frac {nC_V}T \text{d}T$. We take the definite integrales

$ \displaystyle \int_{V_1}^{5V_1} \!\!\!\!\! -\frac 34 \frac{nR}V \text{d}V = \int_{398}^{T_2} \frac {nC_V}T \text{d}T$

and can then finally solve for $T_2$ (it turns out to be approximately $245 \text{ K}$). At last, we can determine the final pressure from

$\displaystyle \frac {p_1V_1}{T_1} = \frac {p_2V_2}{T_2}$.

---

**(1)** My main question is whether you guys know of a different way to solve this problem not involving having to solve differential equations?

**(2)** I've seen the 1st law written as $\text{d}U = \text{d}Q + \text{d}W$ but if we use that expression we definitely won't get the right answer; what's up with the inconsistency?

**(3)** I saw no other option than having to use the molar heat capacity equation $\text{d}U = nC_V\text{d}T$ but doesn't this assume constant volume? In our problem the volume is definitely changing, so is it not contradictory to use that very equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)The First law is written in form of differentials themselves,so I think there may be no escape from using differential equations.

(2)The way most commonly the first law is written is,

> $dU=dQ-dW_{\text{work done by the system}}$.
>
> Here dW is work done **by** the system.

However,in subjects other than physics,more important quantity is the work done by the experimenter.(This is quite common in chemistry)

As the process in thermodynamics are most "quasistatic"(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_process),the container/piston is always in equilibrium.

So, $\vec{F_{ext}}=-\vec{F_{int}}$(they are equal and opposite),then we have,

$dW_{\text{by the system}}=-dW_{\text{on the system}}$.

And so the first law can be written as:

> $dU=dQ+dW_{\text{work done on the system}}$.
>
> Here dW is work done **on** the system.

As the two $dW$s have different meanings we won't a different answer.

(3)**The internal energy of a gas is state variable/state function**(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functions_of_state).

$U$ depends only on the final and initial states of the system and not on what process was used to get from initial to the final state.So we can use a constant volume process to get $dU$ which then can be used in any process without any modification.